# How to disable animation of marker rotation using animarker package

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I am using [flutter_animarker: ^3.4.0-beta.1](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_animarker/versions/3.4.0-beta.1) package.

my code:

```
void newLocationUpdate(LocationObj obj) {
    var marker = RippleMarker(
        markerId: markerId,
        position: obj.latlng,
        ripple: false,
        alpha: 1,
        rotation: obj.rotat,
        icon: sourceIcon,
        anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
        onTap: () {
          // print('Tapped! $obj');
        });
    setState(() => markers[markerId] = marker);
  }
```

widget using:

```
Animarker(
          curve: Curves.linear,
          useRotation: true,
          rippleRadius: 0.5,
          angleThreshold: 1.5,
          duration: duration,
          runExpressAfter: 1,
          rippleDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          mapId: controller.future.then<int>((value) => value.mapId),
          markers: markers.values.toSet(),
          child: GoogleMap(
              polylines: {
                Polyline(
                    width: 2,
                    polylineId: const PolylineId('HTPolyline'),
                    points: locArr.map((element) => element.latlng).toList(),
                    color: const Color.fromARGB(179, 62, 191, 208)),
              },
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: startPosition,
              onMapCreated: (gController) {
                getPositionsHistory().then((latlng) {
                  if (latlng.latitude > 0) {
                    gController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                        CameraPosition(target: latlng, zoom: 14.5)));
                  }
                  stream.forEach((value) => newLocationUpdate(value));
                  controller.complete(gController);
                });
              }),
        )
```

[In this image you can see the 360 degree animated rotation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaf5x.gif)

I tried the useRotation to false and also custom bearing functions but now I just want to disable the animation when marker is rotating.

Comment: Actually, my api's rotations degrees are not using in "RippleMarker".
Is there any solution to use my own custom rotation?